# Specific data from sqlite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

i have sqlite table that contains these informations

```
Id     Nickname    Status
1        john      online
2        Tom       offline
3         .        online
.         .        online
.         .        online
```

So i need all nicknames from table which's status is online and i will turn this data to string array.

i have tried this but it didnt response anything.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass);
PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Nickname FROM USERS WHERE status=?");
pst.setString(1, "Online");

ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();

StringBuilder sbnewer=new StringBuilder();
int ir=1;
sbnewer.append("linestart");

while(rs.next()){
    sbnewer.append(rs.getString(ir)+"and");
    ir++;
}
```

Comment: Well if the database string is "online" and you ask for "Online", it sure as heck won't return anything.

Comment: what do you use as `url`?

Comment: @Kayaman it is my fault. There is no grammatical errors. both code and table has Online/Offline

Comment: Well what do you mean that "it didn't response anything". You're not printing the strinbuilder anywhere, what's the exact code you're using? Copy and paste it, so you don't get syntactical errors.

Comment: @Ruchira url is my location where Users.sqlite folder is. I can easily read data from there there is no problem in that file

Comment: @Kayaman, you shouldn't be so sure. If the column was created with the options "collate nocase", the query would return the values even with the case difference.

Comment: @samuelgrigolato I never give the benefit of the doubt here. People make typos and stupid mistakes all the time, and post them here way too eagerly.

Comment: @Kayaman it should be sending this info by dataoutputstream but stream doesn't get anything from reading.So i tried a simple Read/Write Utf to check is there a problem in stream codes but not it works well. so i was worried about this sql sytax is wrong or not?

Comment: Why are you incrementing the column index? Try removing the "ir++"..

Comment: @samuelgrigolato Yes this was the error I think it fixed reading from table thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem is in the line: sbnewer.append(rs.getString(ir)+"and");

Looking at the docs for getString states the parameter is the COLUMN number that you want to get (note this is not the ROW number a you seems to assume). Each call to rs.next gets you the next row, but you always want column 0 (the first one - NickName) So the entire usage of ir seems incorrect.

If you remove the ir variable and replace the above line with simply: sbnewer.append(rs.getString(0)+"and");
You will get what you want.